# Node js commander args returns true instead the value

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I want to create a script with node and node commander and when i try to grab the values of my args i get the value true instead the value itself.

For example if i write this in terminal:

```
node myfile.js -s somefile -d test

var program = require('commander');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .option('-s, --src', 'src csv file')
  .option('-d, --destination', 'destination csv file')
  .parse(process.argv);

console.log(program.src); // return true
console.log(program.destination); // return true
```

How i get the value of this args?

Comment: Can you please include the output from: `console.log(JSON.stringify(program));` Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) isn't very clear and only shows this by example, but the syntax you have used (`'-s, --src'`) is for boolean values.

If you want to take a string you need to say so: `'-s, --src <item>'`

Answer (score 12):

You aren't specifying that the options take input. You can do this by including `<data>` or `[data]` (if optional) in your option definitions:

`.option('-s, --src <src>', 'src csv file')
.option('-d, --dest [dest]', 'destination csv file')`

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify that the options take an argument and that they are not just a flag

```
program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .option('-s, --src <file>', 'src csv file')
  .option('-d, --destination <file>', 'destination csv file')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

If the argument is mandatory, it is specified with `<>`. If it is optional, with `[]`.